# Turning Off RAID In Order to Install Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: system-installation, hp, raid

Here is my story. I purchase an HP laptop that came preinstalled with Windows 10. I did not want Windows so I installed Kubuntu in which I am currently using version 20.4. I am having all sorts of problems and I am pretty convinced that they are isolated to Kubuntu. For example, I have 3 other Acer laptops that was also having the same problems plus some while running Kubuntu. I switched them to Ubuntu and they are running awesomely. All of those problems are now gone. I would like the same for my HP laptop. However, when I try to install Ubuntu, I get a message that the installer has detected that I have RAID devices and it cannot continue. It directed me to a support page which did not help. I looked in BIOS and I have two drives, one is just under 2 TB and the other is 14 GB. For both, it says that they are Non-RAID. To me that is confusing.

I tried contacting HP but that was a bust since they kept pushing me to use Windows and never would tell me how to fix it. So now I am coming in hopes that I can get some help. The model name of my laptop is HP Laptop 17-by0089cl. I used Ubuntu sometime ago for awhile and it was very nice. I had to briefly go to Windows 10 before now being on Kubuntu but I would just like to go back to Ubuntu and stay put.

Comment: "*An error message*" is a lot like "*a cough*" -- too vague to be useful. We need to see the exact, complete error message.

Comment: I never said anything about an error message. It is just a message screen that appears during the installation. As I said above, all it says is that the installer detected a RAID device and cannot continue. No more explanation needed. Pretty easy concept. It is funny how you say you need more information but I have already posted that same message elsewhere and have no one has had an issue understanding how to help me. Maybe if you do not understand my post to help, maybe you are not the one I need to be helping me.